# How to use ARRAYFORMULA and UNIQUE together in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

How can I expand the `UNIQUE` function using `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Example:
Here is my data set, also can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16R7NFwZXIPFV0SR3-Mo08hqZvNQ8jNBLTEkTUAkDGPU/edit#gid=0).
I want to see the unique values of each row in next columns.

```
CL1 | CL2 | CL3 | CL4
JAN | FEB | FEB | JAN >> JAN | FEB
MAR | MAR | JUN | AUG >> MAR | JUN | AUG
NOV | OCT | OCT | OCT >> NOV | OCT
SEP | OCT | JUN | MAR >> SEP | OCT | JUN | MAR
```

[image: ARRAYFORMULA and UNIQUE together in Google Sheets]

I have used the following formula in cell E2:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2)))
```

But, the problem is that I need to copy the exact formula in the following rows. While I would prefer to use `ARRAYFORMULA`.

The problem is that, since `ARRAYFORMULA` is also using data range, like `UNIQUE`, there is a conflict.
I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE({A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,D2:D}))))
```

In other words, I want the exact same result but using `ARRAYFORMULA` instead of manually entering the formula for each row.

Any other solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- not all regular formulas can be converted into array formulas. in this case, you can go only semiautomatic like:

  ```
  ={TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2)));
    TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A3:D3)));
    TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A4:D4)));
    TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A5:D5)));
    TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A6:D6)))}
  ```